# Nest js getting user id from the session in the websocket listener

Tags: nestjs, passport.js

I'm trying to get the userId inside the websocket listener i've done a ton of google searches about the topic but without any progress.
I'm using passport ,express-session packages.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific regarding user ID's. I see you are using passport to implement your session authentication.  What particular passport authentication are you using? Passport Google Auth, passport Discord etc., there are plenty. Generally, the session data is what you are looking for if the user id is stored that way.

The session cookie or session store will contain the authentication data you are looking for. If you are using express-session, this information can be obtained by looking at the "req.user" aka Request user. Whatever you store for session data will come up in the req if the user is authenticated through Passport.